# Position a pseudo elements li :after beyond li

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a menu with a ul list.

I need to add a small text below each `<li>`

Unfortunately i can’t add the html elements because it is a native CMS menu (i can make an override but i would like to find an other way).

so here is what i’ve done :

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/6dcnztax/

I apply a `position: relative;` to the `<li>` and a `position: absolute;` to the `li:after`

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="item-131">text 1</li>
    <li class="item-132">text 2</li>
    <li class="item-133">text 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    font-size: 16px;
}
ul li {
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
}
.item-131 {
    position: relative;
}
.item-131:after {
    content:"small text 1";
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #88857d;
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.item-132:after {
    content:"small text 2";
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #88857d;
    width: 100%;
}
.item-133:after {
    content:"small text 3";
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #88857d;
}
```

Do you know if there is a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/xyr1b29q/1/

```
ul {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li {
    min-height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
}

ul li:after {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #88857d;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


.item-131:after { content:"small text 1"; }
.item-132:after { content:"small text 2"; }
.item-133:after { content:"small text 3"; }
```

There's no really need to use `relative/absolute` position to place a text in a new line.

Use a `min-height` instead of `height` for the list-item. Also define all style properties for `:after` pseudoelement just once.

---

Resulting screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I had tried before with `display:block` but as the height was fixed, the element was not shown. With `min-height`, it’s ok.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use jquery for append a span and insert text in span tag. That will help for dynamic content also.

Comment: I’ve also thought of this solution but i prefer to only use CSS.